# Unable to find error in my logic in a codechef july challenge

Tags: c++

Chef has a calculator which has two screens and two buttons. Initially, each screen shows the number zero. Pressing the first button increments the number on the first screen by 1, and each click of the first button consumes 1 unit of energy.

Pressing the second button increases the number on the second screen by the number which is currently appearing on the first screen. Each click of the second button consumes B units of energy.

Initially the calculator has N units of energy.

Now chef wonders what the maximum possible number is, that he gets on the second screen of the calculator, with the limited energy.
Here is the link: https://www.codechef.com/JULY17/problems/CALC/

Contest is ended, so I am not trying to cheat.
here is my solution to the problem:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n,b;
        cin>>n>>b;
        int count = 1;
        int ans = n-b;
        while((n - count*b)>=0)
        {
            if(count*(n - count*b)>ans)
                ans = count*(n - count*b);
            count++;
        }
        cout<<ans<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried every test case that i can think of... Can anyone help to find the error in my logic.

Comment: Please read why you should avoid both [`bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namesapce std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Most of all, avoid using them together.

Comment: First please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: More importantly, I'm missing the error description from the question.

Comment: @MSalters there is no error as such, but none of the test cases are passing... manually i have tried every case which i can think of... My answer is correct for all those cases... Problem must be in the logic, which i am not able to get...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can you suggest any test case for which my solution will return a wrong answer???

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you for this advice... I wasn't aware about this

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the links

Comment: can you show a test case for which it returns correct answer?

Comment: @tobi303 yeah it passes for basic case given in the question... as well as i tried with large values with in the limit of int and also various possible combinations of n and b

Comment: @Ron I wouldnt be so negative. True, they dont make you learn the language, they dont make you write nice code, they are a waste of time, but still they can be fun ;)

Comment: To be fair to online judges, they are good at forcing you to think about your edge cases (as long as the test cases are well designed).

Comment: How about `b` equal to zero? That will give an endless loop.

Comment: b>=1 always @4386427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors that I think can be:

1: You didn't handle N<=B case

```
if (n<=b) {
    ans = 0;
}
```

2: you didn't handle Subtask 2 Constraints

```
long long int ans = n-b;
```

3: lastly answer will be n-b if b is three time less than equal to n

```
if (n<=3*b) {
    ans = n-b;
}
```

4: Look for a straight forward approach

```
k1 = ((n-(b+1))/(2*b))+1;
i2 = (double((n-(3*b)))/(2*b));
i1 = ceil(i2);
i = n-((3*b)+((i1-1)*(2*b)));
ans = ((2*b)*((k1*(k1-1))/2))+(k1*i);
cout << ans;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i didn't get your 3rd point... why do i need to handle n>=3*b??

Comment: @UtkarshVaish This is something I found out by dry running the problem, you might not need to handle this condition if you have solid logic

Comment: my solution automatically takes care of that...

Comment: when i handled 1st and 2nd mistakes pointed by you, first subtask passed correctly

Comment: @UtkarshVaish If you didn't get 100 points, then there is definitely a logical error in your code. Deeply analyze the cases and try to understand the task at hand and your code flow

Comment: I just wanted some test case, which returns wrong answer to my solution

Answer (score 0):

It is a mostly a mathematical question:
With

- `N` unit of energy
- `B` energy cost of 2nd screen
- `p` number of time 1st button clicked
- `s` number of time 2nd button clicked

You try to maximize

- `s * p`

whereas

`p + B * s <= N`

so

`p <= N - B * s`

and then

maximize: `N * s - B * s²`

```
s0 = 0
s1 = N / B
```

sMax is `(s0 + s1) / 2` -> `N / (2*B)`

so max value is

```
N²/2B - N²/4B -> N²/4B
```

so

```
std::cin >> n >> b;
std::cout << n * n / b / 4 << std::endl
```